# In Android Programming,what is the point of layout_width if it does nothing?

Tags: android-layout

Changing android:layout_width in the below xml to any value (like 99999dp for eg) does not seem to do anything when i run the emulator via android studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should specify which element you are trying to resize

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText` has `android:layout_weight="1"`. When using weights the width is not taken in account and should be set to 0. If you remove the weight you should be able to set the width as desired.

Comment: Thank you for answering , and I am sorry for the totally noob question, but can you please explain why bother assigning value to android:layout_width if it is not taken in account when android:layout_weight="1". I took this snippet from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: What `layout_weight` does is it computes size of the element as percentage instead of fixed value. In this case `EditText` is the only element with weight and that means it takes 100% of the space available. Since it is in a `LinearLayout` with a `Button` that means it takes all the space that is left after the size of the `Button` is determined. Anyway I think weights are tricky and I try to avoid them.